# Find the first Triangular number which has 50 factors?

Tags: c#, algorithm, number-theory

-----Modification of code requested --------

Question : Count the Fast Triangular Series Number which is having 50 Factors ?

Elaborated : Let's say there is a series

```
   1 : 1
   3 : 1+2
   6 : 1+2+3 
   10 : 1+2+3+4
   15 : 1+2+3+4+5
   21 : 1+2+3+4+5+6
   28 : 1+2+3+4+5+6+7
```

here 1,3,6,10,15,21,28 are the numbers coming under triangular series.

lets see the factors of the number

```
    Number factors         Count
    1     : 1               1              
    3     : 1,3             2
    6     : 1,2,3,6         4
    10    : 1,2,5,10        4
    15    : 1,3,5,15        4
    21    : 1,3,7,21        4
    28    : 1,2,4,7,14,28   6
```

here 6 is the first triangular number which is having 4 factors.
 even if 10,15,21 also having 4 factors but they are not the 1st one.
 Like that lets take a number as 2 which is having 2 factors as 1 and 2
 same for number 3 also having 2 factors as 1 and 3

but as per question 3 will be the answer not 2 because 2 is not coming under Triangular series number list even if it is faster than 3.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming. 

Comment: [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12)?

Comment: Yes JNF, but what i need is proper solution(steps/Logic) for the above question. I got the output but i hope better code can be written. That's why requesting a solution which is better than my given logic.

Comment: @razlebe, algorithm questions are ok on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See [this](http://www.mathblog.dk/triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors/) for an example of "better code".

Comment: AFAIR, as you answer the question on Project Euler, you are automatically granted an access to the forum topic to share your solution to the world and to read others. These posts are a great source of better logic.

Comment: I'll repeat my question to the OP directly: are we talking *exactly* 50 or *more than* 50? Because the Project Euler problem states "first triangle number to have *over* five hundred divisors"

Comment: @lance Even when unsupported by any code?

Comment: @razlebe - the code is in OPs own answer. Not a good way to do it, but it's something, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Solution :
> >     Let me break down the Question in multiple modules.
> >
> > 1) Find the triangular series till a number.
> >
> > 2) Store all identified numbers in a List of integers
> >
> > 3) Find the no of factors for a particular number
> >
> > 4) Loop trough the each item of triangular series and find the count of factors for each number.
> >
> > 5) check the the first one whose count is 50 then display the value
> >
> > 6) write break statement to show only the first 50th number.

## Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace IsNumberTringularSeriesConsoleApp
{ 
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Listing all numbers comes under Triangular series.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="number"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static List<int> GetTriangularNumbers(int number)
        {
            List<int> lstTriangularNumbers = new List<int>();
            int i;
            int sum = 0;
            int triangularNumber = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < number; i++)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
                triangularNumber = sum;
                lstTriangularNumbers.Add(triangularNumber);
            }
            return lstTriangularNumbers;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// returns(count) the number of factors for each number
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="number"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int FactorCount(int number)
        {
            List<int> factors = new List<int>();
            int max = (int)Math.Sqrt(number);  //round down
            for (int factor = 1; factor <= max; ++factor)
            { 
                //test from 1 to the square root, or the int below it, inclusive.
                if (number % factor == 0)
                {
                    factors.Add(factor);
                    if (factor != number / factor)
                   {
                     // Don't add the square root twice!  
                        factors.Add(number / factor);
                   }
                }
            }
            return factors.Count;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> lstTriangularNumbers = new List<int>();
            List<int> factors = new List<int>();
            int count = 0;
            //Getting the list of numbers comes under triangular series till 5000
            lstTriangularNumbers = GetTriangularNumbers(5000);

            foreach (int number in lstTriangularNumbers)
            {
                /*
                 * Calling the FactorCount(number) function to check no of factors 
                 * available for the specific triangular number - number.
                 */
                 count = FactorCount(number);
                 //Console.WriteLine("No of factors for : " + number + " is : " + count);
                if (count == 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No of factors for first Triangular Number : " + number + " is : " + count);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: OP could presumably substitute `BigInteger`, although it might take a bit of work

Comment: Boss, it's giving output as "No of factors for first Triangular Number : 3357936 is 50 " which is correct. I need a better code.

Comment: First thing to "make better": your `FactorCount` and `GetFactors` basically have the same body. So just have `FactorCount` be `return GetFactors(number).Count;`. And again, have a look at [mathblog](http://www.mathblog.dk/triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors/) to see other ways to cut down execution time significantly. Or what exactly do you mean by "better" code?

Comment: And I'd change the `GetTriangularNumbers` to something like this: `public static IEnumerable<int> GetTriangularInt32() { var sum = 0; var i = 1; while (Int32.MaxValue - sum >= i) { sum += i++; yield return sum; } }` since you `foreach` & `break` over it anyways, you don't have to create unnecessary numbers beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

Triangle number #2591 = 3357936 is the first one that has *exactly* 50 factors: 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 16, 18, 24, 27, 36, 48, 54, 72, 81, 108, 144, 162, 216, 324, 432, 648, 1296, 2591, 5182, 7773, 10364, 15546, 20728, 23319, 31092, 41456, 46638, 62184, 69957, 93276, 124368, 139914, 186552, 209871, 279828, 373104, 419742, 559656, 839484, 1119312, 1678968, 3357936

Triangle number #12375 = 76576500 is the first one that has *at least* 500 factors (actually 576 factors): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, ..., 19144125, 25525500, 38288250, 76576500

Triangle number #1569375 = 1231469730000 is the first one that has *exactly* 500 factors

The solution code itself is very easy, providing you can get divisors:

```
   public static long Solution(int factorsCount) {
      for (long i = 1; ; ++i) {
        long n = i * (i + 1) / 2;

        IList<long> factors = GetDivisors(n);

        // This code tests if a triangle number has exactly factorsCount factors
        // if you want to find out a triangle number which has at least factorsCount factors
        // change "==" comparison to ">=" one:
        // if (factors.Count >= factorsCount)  
        if (factors.Count == factorsCount) 
          return n;
      }
    }

  ...

  long solution = Solution(50);
```

If you haven't got a routine to get number's factors, you can use this one:

```
// Get prime divisors 
private static IList<long> CoreGetPrimeDivisors(long value, IList<int> primes) {
  List<long> results = new List<long>();

  int v = 0;
  long threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < primes.Count; ++i) {
    v = primes[i];

    if (v > threshould)
      break;

    if ((value % v) != 0)
      continue;

    while ((value % v) == 0) {
      value = value / v;

      results.Add(v);
    }

    threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);
  }

  if (value > 1)
    results.Add(value);

  return results;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get prime divisors 
/// </summary>
public static IList<long> GetPrimeDivisors(long value, IList<int> primes) {
  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, primes))
    return CoreGetPrimeDivisors(value, primes);

  List<long> results = new List<long>();

  while ((value % 2) == 0) {
    results.Add(2);

    value = value / 2;
  }

  while ((value % 3) == 0) {
    results.Add(3);

    value = value / 3;
  }

  while ((value % 5) == 0) {
    results.Add(5);

    value = value / 5;
  }

  while ((value % 7) == 0) {
    results.Add(7);

    value = value / 7;
  }

  int v = 0;
  long n = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) / 6.0 + 1);
  long threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);

  for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
    v = 6 * i - 1;

    if ((value % v) == 0) {
      while ((value % v) == 0) {
        results.Add(v);

        value = value / v;
      }

      threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);
    }

    v = 6 * i + 1;

    if ((value % v) == 0) {
      while ((value % v) == 0) {
        results.Add(v);

        value = value / v;
      }

      threshould = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 1);
    }

    if (v > threshould)
      break;
  }

  if (value > 1) {
    if (results.Count <= 0)
      results.Add(value);
    else if (value != results[results.Count - 1])
      results.Add(value);
  }

  return results;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get all divisors
/// </summary>
public static IList<long> GetDivisors(long value, IList<int> primes) {
  HashSet<long> hs = new HashSet<long>();

  IList<long> divisors = GetPrimeDivisors(value, primes);

  ulong n = (ulong) 1;
  n = n << divisors.Count;

  for (ulong i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    ulong v = i;
    long p = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < divisors.Count; ++j) {
      if ((v % 2) != 0)
        p *= divisors[j];

      v = v / 2;
    }

    hs.Add(p);
  }

  List<long> result = new List<long>();

  result.Add(1);

  var en = hs.GetEnumerator();

  while (en.MoveNext())
    result.Add(en.Current);

  result.Sort();

  return result;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get all divisors
/// </summary>
public static IList<long> GetDivisors(long value) {
  return GetDivisors(value, null);
}
```

Comment: Huh, am I doing something wrong? With my algorithm for 50 I get `#224 is 25200: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 28, 30, 35, 36, 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 56, 60, 63, 70, 72, 75, 80, 84, 90, 100, 105, 112, 120, 126, 140, 144, 150, 168, 175, 180, 200, 210, 225, 240, 252, 280, 300, 315, 336, 350, 360, 400, 420, 450, 504, 525, 560, 600, 630, 700, 720, 840, 900, 1008, 1050, 1200, 1260, 1400, 1575, 1680, 1800, 2100, 2520, 2800, 3150, 3600, 4200, 5040, 6300, 8400, 12600, 25200`. Same algorithm yields `#12375 is 76576500` for 500...

Comment: Wait... are we talking *exactly* 50 or *more than* 50? Because the Project Euler problem states "first triangle number to have *over* five hundred divisors"

Comment: Just change the comparison from "==" to ">=" (see my comments) and you'll find out triangle numbers that have at least 50 or 500 factors.
So, the triangle number #2591 = 3357936 has excatly 50 factors, #1569375 = 1231469730000 has exactly 500 factors, 
#224 = 25200 has at least 50 factors (actually 90) and #12375 = 76576500 has at least 500 factors (actually 576)

Answer (score 3):

here is my answer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TriangularSeries
{
    class MyClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result;
            TriangularSeries aSeries = new TriangularSeries();
            result = aSeries.TSeries();
            Console.WriteLine("The first Triangular Series number that has 50Factors is : " + result);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    //Find the Triangular Series numbers
    class TriangularSeries
    {
        public int TSeries()
        {
            int fCount = 0, T1 = 1, i = 1, T2 = 0, fval = 0;
            while (fCount != 50)
            {
                i += 1;
                T2 = T1 + i;

                fCount = CalcFactors(T1);
                fval = T1;                   
                T1 = T2;

            }
            return fval;
        }

        public int CalcFactors(int num1)
        {

            List<int> factors = new List<int>();
            int max = (int)Math.Sqrt(num1);  //round down
            for (int factor = 1; factor <= max; ++factor)
            {
                //test from 1 to the square root, or the int below it, inclusive.
                if (num1 % factor == 0)
                {
                    factors.Add(factor);
                    if (factor != num1 / factor)
                    {
                        // Don't add the square root twice!  
                        factors.Add(num1 / factor);
                    }
                }
            }
            return factors.Count;

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my program in C language

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;
int num1=0,num2=1;
int a[3000];
int tri_series()         //This function finds the Triangular series numbers
{
    for(i=0;num2<=3000;i++)
    {
    num1=num1+num2;
    a[i]=num1;
    num2++;
    }
}
int main()
{
tri_series();            //Calling the function tri_series
int num,count;
    for(i=0;i<=3000;i++)
    {
      count=0;
      for(num=1;num<=a[i];num++)
      {
        if(a[i]%num==0)  //Finds the factors of each Triangular Series Number 
        count=count+1;   
      }
      if(count==50)      //Break at the first Triangular Series Number having 50 factors
      {
       printf("%d:%d\t",a[i],count);
       break;
      }
    }
}
```

Performance issue:
This code generates a performance issue when comes to execution time. It takes "a minute" to execute and display the output.

Comment: Thanks anu. Thanks for the answer in c version. Will be helpful for C programmers.

Comment: But there are few modifications are required. num2 is not defined,int main doesnot return any value. please modify the program such that it will be helpful for C programmers.

Comment: The a[i] values are printed in the main function, the tri_series function is just defined and called in main function. Thanks for the correction Chandan.